# Unable to get data from API with axios: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to retrieve an object from an API with axios, but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

Pasting the same url in the browser gives me the correct view of the object, I don't know where the error is.

Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php")
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
  });
```

Comment: The URL is wrong. It should be www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php

Comment: My bad, the url actually included the final .php, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you pass the invaild url to axios

//www.domain.com/page

the scheme may be not the same for the two requests
and the request headers are not the same

you should check the two requests.

most times, http and https do not response the same thing